# Generate random matrix with specific rank

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am wondering how it is possible to generate an n x n matrix in Matlab with a specific rank (number of pivot columns). I know that you can use the command `randi(IMAX, m, n)` to generate an m x n matrix with random entries between 1 and IMAX, but is it possible, for example, to generate a 4 x 4 matrix with random entries but only 2 pivot columns? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably belongs on [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com) or [su]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I realized that because `randi(IMAX, m, n)` forms an m x n matrix with as many pivot columns as possible, that it's possible to form an n x n matrix A with k pivot columns and random entries between 1 and IMAX with the following code:

```
A = randi(IMAX, n, k)*randi(IMAX, k, n)
```

Because each of `randi(IMAX, n, k)` and `randi(IMAX, k, n)` only have `k` pivot columns so their product will only have k pivot columns as well.

Comment: Note that this will not generate uniform distribution on that space and also the elements will fall in the range [1,IMAX^2].

Comment: +1 this is the right approach and should work whether you're generating using `rand`, `randi`, or `randn`. Frequently, you might also use the same matrix, ie `X = randn(4, 2);`, `Y = X * X';`. Also, I edited your answer to include code highlighting. Cheers.

Comment: Mr. Bowers, thanks for cleaning it up and making it look professional. Best of luck!

Comment: The range of elements is in fact [1, IMAX^2 * k].

Answer (score 1):

One (admittedly inefficient) method might be to generate the full matrix (4x4 in your example), then separate it using SVD decomposition and zero some of the singular values (2 entries in your case). I believe the recomposed matrix will have the desired rank.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you are interested in controlling the singular values of the generated matrix, you can use the randSVD function from the test matrices gallery: [(link)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gallery.html#f84-1000189)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm creating a loop until and unless it is creating a random matrix of 2. You can change the number as required. (Note: Rank of a matrix cannot be greater than than the size of a matrix)

Below is the Matlab Code:

```
Matrix_Size=input('Enter a number to generate the desired matrix\n')

Iteration = 2 % This is to run the loop infinitely

while (Iteration>1)
    Main_Matrix=sym(randi(7,3,3)) %7 is the range where the elements in my random matrix will occur
    Rank_Matrix=rank(Main_Matrix)
    if (Rank_Matrix == 2)
        break
    end
end
Main_Matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%random number with specific rank
close all;
clc;
clear;
rng(8);
y= randi(300,3,3);
display(y)
if rank(y)==2
    y=y;

else
    r = (randi(9)+1);
    for i = 1:3
       y(3,i)=r*y(1,i);
    end
end

%random number with specific rank
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%%plotting the figures column space - left null space
figure(1)
plot3([0 CS(1,1)],[0 CS(2,1)],[0 CS(3,1)],'r','linew',3)
hold on
plot3([0 CS(1,2)],[0 CS(2,2)],[0 CS(3,2)],'b','linew',3)
legend('CS - Column 1','CS - Column 2')
hold on 
plot3([0 LNS(1,1)],[0 LNS(2,1)],[0 LNS(3,1)],'g','linew',3)
legend('CS - Column 1','CS - Column 2','LNS - Column 1')
title('Column Space - Left Null Space Plot')
hold off
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
%%matrix decalration and finding the  column space, row space and null
%%space and left null space
clear;clc;clear all variables;
B=randi(16,3,2);
C=randi(16,2,3);
A=B*C;
rank(A);
Y=sym(A);
Y
CS = colspace(Y)
RS = colspace(Y')
NS = null(Y)
LNS = null(Y')
```